# Equivalence relation of absolute values in the definition of primes/places of an algebraic number field

Tags: reference-request, definition, algebraic-number-theory, absolute-value

I am trying to get into algebraic number theory and found the following definition which I would like to understand:

**Definition** Let $K$ be an algebraic number field. An equivalence class of absolute values on $K$ is called a **prime** or **place** of $K$.

> **Question** What is the underlying equivalence relation of absolute values of $K$ in this definition?

I would be grateful for an explanation or a reference that explains that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two absolute values on a field $K$ are called *equivalent* if they define the same topology on the field (same as saying they define the same notion of "convergent sequence" in $K$). It can be proved that two absolute values are equivalent if and only if they are positive powers of each other. This does *not* mean every positive power of an absolute value is in fact an absolute value since a power of one might not satisfy the triangle inequality: if $|\cdot|$ is the usual absolute value on $\mathbf R$ or $\mathbf C$ then $|\cdot|^r$ is an absolute value for $0 < r \leq 1$ but not for $r > 1$ because $|\cdot|^r$ for $r > 1$ does not satisfy the triangle inequality. If $|\cdot|$ is a nonarchimedean absolute value then every positive power of it is a nonarchimedean absolute value.

When $K$ is a number field, it has the following inequivalent absolute values on $K$:

(1) $|\sigma(x)|$ for a real embedding $\sigma \colon K \to \mathbf R$,

(2) $|\sigma(x)|$ for a complex (non-real) embedding $\sigma \colon K \to \mathbf C$, where $\sigma$ and $\overline{\sigma}$ define the same absolute value on $K$ (for technical reasons related to the product formula, we may use $|\sigma(x)|^2$ as "the absolute value" here even though it does not fit the triangle inequality),

(3) the $\mathfrak p$-adic absolute value $|x|_{\mathfrak p} = (1/{\rm N}(\mathfrak p))^{{\rm ord}_{\mathfrak p}(x)}$ for a nonzero prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ in the ring of integers of $K$.

Theorem: *Every nontrivial absolute value on $K$ is equivalent to exactly one of the absolute values described above.*

Because each nontrivial absolute value on $K$, up to equivalence, corresponds to exactly one of the different (nonzero) prime ideals of the integers of $K$ or a real embedding or  a pair of conjugate complex embeddings, an equivalence class of nontrivial absolute values on $K$ is called a "prime" of $K$.